# Using Javascript on Mac get selected row number from Numbers spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, macos, numbers

I'm trying to get the selected row number from a Numbers spreadsheet on a Mac mini II. Try as I might, all my attempts (copied from examples on the web) result in the error message "Error -1700: Can't convert types". It seems like it should be simple but I don't know Javascript and Numbers syntax well enough and all I ever get is that message.
An example tried is "var selectedRow = table.selectionRange.Row. which produces that message.

Can someone suggest a way to do it?